# Rewrite native iOS app with Titanium or Rhodes

Tags: ios, titanium, rhodes

I have an iOS app in the AppStore, built with Xcode a while ago, but I am thinking of rewriting it from scratch to iron out some bad decisions and this time use some cross-platform framework such as [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com) or [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com) to add Android support also.

Is it possible for my current iOS users to seamlessly upgrade to the new version, retaining their userdata (of course a migrator is required in the new app). I think I have to retain some app identifier or other data in the new version.

Or should I create it as totally new app and let the users migrate their data (possibly using the `Open in...` scheme).
The downside of this is that current users must re-purchase the app, which might drive some of them away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible for my current iOS users to seamlessly upgrade to the new version, retaining their userdata (of course a migrator is required in the new app). I think I have to retain some app identifier or other data in the new version.

In principle, it is possible. The fact that you are moving to a different development platform will not affect your ability to access data already stored by the user. In the end, it greatly depends on how you stored that data: if it is through `NSUserDefaults`, it will be pretty much transparent; if it is in XML/JSON files, you will need to add some XML/JSON parser to you new app (provided Appcelerator Titanium or Rhodes do not already provide one); if it is through sqlite, I know that, e.g., Titanium supports it; if it is through Core Data, maybe you will need to write some kind of converter for the existing data. But, in the end, it is definitely possible.

> Or should I create it as totally new app and let the users migrate their data (possibly using the Open in... scheme). The downside of this is that current users must re-purchase the app, which might drive some of them away.

What you should take into account here is how much the new app will differ from the old one. If there is a risk of disappointing your customer base, maybe you can go for a separate version. It is clear that doing so will bother some users that will have paid for the old version. One scheme that has been applied in at least one case I know of is offering the app for free during an initial period. But whether this is sensible or not depends entirely on the prospects of your apps.

Maybe the best approach is striving for a largely improved new version, so that disappointed customers will be the least possible number, and keep the same bundle id for a seamless update.

Comment: I think I could do a new cross-platform version and submit it to Android store and see where it takes me and only then decide if seamless upgrade from iOS is possible or should I keep two versions.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest refactoring your current iOS codebase as opposed to rewriting it from scratch. Rewriting from scratch is almost always the wrong decision when you can refactor and clean up code as you go. It will always be harder than you expect, take longer than you expect, and often won't end up providing the benefit you expected it to. Refactoring is cheaper, faster, and safer.

In my opinion you would be doing your users a disservice by rewriting the app using cross-platform framework after they are used to a fully native app written in Objective-C. You would be doing yourself a disservice by throwing away code. Bad code can be fixed, no matter how ugly it is now.

I would suggest writing your Android app using Java and refactor your iOS app once the Android app is finished. You can provide the best experience for both platforms this way. The reason to add Android support first is because you already have a working iOS app in the store, so you're 1/2 way there already without touching a cross-platform framework. Writing the Android app should also allow you to flesh out ideas of how to refactor the iOS app.

As far as upgrading your current users, you need to keep the bundle ID the same in order for users to be able to seamlessly upgrade via the app store. Upgrading their data is also possible, but you need to provide more details on how that data is stored within your current app. If at all possible, the automatic upgrade is preferable to an Open In... scheme that requires the user to manually load their settings.

Comment: Thanks. I have considered refactoring but this will only give me new iOS app, and Android version would take at least as much time. Taking into account that my app is rather simple, I don't think cross-platform drawbacks would affect it that much, but it would give me Android version almost "for free". Plus, I know both Ruby and JS a lot better than either ObjC or Java.